# trying to update JSON file in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON file 'DealerList.json' and I can access it from my app by importing it using

```
import DealerList from './json/DealerList'
let tasks = DealerList;
```

The *tasks* here contain the JSON and I can easily access it.
Is there any way by which I can update the JSON back like if I update the values  OR if I delete the values. I have also tried *require("fs")* but that too is throwing error.

The JSON file is present in a folder called json in the React App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and this is a good thing. You do not want any web browser to be able to come along and rewrite files on your HTTP server.

Write a web service which will read and update the data based on HTTP requests (with appropriate authentication/authorization to stop undesirables from changing the data). Then interact with it via XMLHttpRequest / fetch / an abstraction library wrapping one of them (like axios).

(Or use localStorage if you want to store the data on a per-browser basis rather than shared between visitors).